# Load XML file into String variable

Tags: java

I want to create XML which is stored into String variable. I tried this:

JAXB Object:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="sale")
public class Sale {

    String ssl_merchant_id;
    String ssl_user_id;
...
}


        Sale obj = new Sale();
        obj.setSsl_merchant_id("1233333");
        obj.setSsl_user_id("svsvsdv");

        try {

            File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Sale.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, System.out);
            String value = jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, null);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How I can store the produced XML into String variable?

Comment: Marshaling as you are doing is the right way. What does your "value" String contain?

Comment: what's the point of marshaling if all you want is xml like what you started with? sounds like `String.join("", Files.readAllLines(Path.get("C:\\file.xml")));
` would be fine.